# Calculating a SHA for a persistent data structure

Tags: clojure

Is there a library to calculate some sort of a `SHA` for persistent data structures?

`(sha (pr-str <datastructure>))` does not work because sometimes the order of keys are not the same when printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it isn't a cryptographic function, `clojure.core/hash-unordered-coll` will give you a consistent hash value as long as the collections have the same contents, and maybe you can leverage on that:

```
user=> (hash-unordered-coll (sorted-map :b 2 :a 1))
161871944
user=> (hash-unordered-coll {:b 2, :a 1})
161871944
user=> (hash-unordered-coll [[:b 2] [:a 1]])
161871944
```

See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-unordered-coll

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want it for. For the simplest use cases, `clojure.core/hash` is fine. But since "data structure" is a much more complicated input format than "sequence of bytes", there's no obvious universal concept of a fingerprint - you have to decide what features it needs.

Comment: All of the cryptographically strong hash functions that I know of are functions of a _sequence_ of bits.  To use one of those, you would need to choose a predictable order for unordered persistent data structures.  For restricted sets of values as set elements/map keys, e.g. integers or strings, it is straightforward to define an order.  For arbitrary mixes of different types of set elements/map keys, it is not so easy to define a total order that covers arbitrary collections.  Hacky partial code here: https://clojure.org/guides/comparators#_comparators_that_work_between_different_types

Answer (score 1):

I found via Google search the following question and discussion of whether there is a cryptographically strong way to combine crypto-strong hash values of elements of an unordered set, into a crypto-strong hash for the entire set, ignoring order.  One answer claims that sorting the hash values of the elements into one string of bits, then calculating a crypto-strong hash on that string, should be strong.  XORing or adding the hashes of the elements together is not.  I did not read all responses, so there may be better approaches known: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54544/how-to-to-calculate-the-hash-of-an-unordered-set

Answer (score 1):

The function [tupelo.lexical/compare-generic](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.lexical#compare-generic)  implements a comparitor that is safe to use across different types.  You could combine this with `sorted-map-by` and `sorted-set-by` in order to convert all maps/sets into stable versions that always print in the same order.  Then the technique of `(sha (pr-str XXX))` would work.

The above logic is already available in the function  [tupelo.core/unlazy](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.core#unlazy). The function [tupelo.misc/str->sha](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.misc#str-%3Esha) also does what it says on the tin. So now, the final solution becomes:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require 
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.misc :as tm] ))

(tm/str->sha (pr-str (t/unlazy XXX)))
```

where `XXX` is any Clojure collection.   Demo code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.misc :as tm]))

(dotest
  (let [stuff     {:hello     "there"
                   1          [2 3 4]
                   "gooodbye" #{"cruel" :world}
                   'forever   ['and "ever" :and #{"ever" 'more}]}
        stuff-str (pr-str (t/unlazy stuff))
        stuff-sha (tm/str->sha (pr-str (t/unlazy stuff)))]
    (is= stuff-str
      "{:hello \"there\", forever [and \"ever\" :and #{more \"ever\"}], 1 [2 3 4], \"gooodbye\" #{:world \"cruel\"}}")
    (is= stuff-sha "af3ade069e7a33139f5ee1fd1d35fd82807e3b1c")))
```